# Entity Association syntax issue with graphql queries

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I am trying to understand graphql's query and mutation syntax. Given this example:

```
type Author {
  id: Int!
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  posts: [Post]
}

type Post {
  id: Int!
  title: String
  author: Author
  votes: Int
}

type Query {
  posts: [Post]
  author(id: Int!): Author
}
```

What should the queries look like to associate a post with the author? Is this where connections come into play or is that something else? Here is my attempt at trying to solve the problem but to avail.

```
mutation createAuthor {
  createAuthor(input: {
    id: 123
    firstName: "Bob"
    lastName: "Smith"
  }) {
    id
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}

query listAuthors {
  listAuthors {
    items {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
}

mutation createPost {
  createPost(input: {
    id: 12345
    title: "Title"
    votes: 345
    author: {
      lastName: {
        contains: "Bob"
      }
    }
  }) {
    id
    title
    votes
    author {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
}
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. My Goal is to Query an author and return all of the post's associated with that author as well as create a Post Mutation that adds a post to an author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 questions in one, so I'll answer in the order there were asked.

**1. return all of the posts associated with an author**

Your schema looks correct. The query would look like:

```
query {
  author(id: 1) {
    id
    posts {
      id 
      title
    }
  }
}
```

**2. create Post and attach to an author**

In your example if you want to expose an interface to create a Post, then you would have to expose a mutation field in your schema

e.g:

```
type Mutation {
  createPost(input: CreatePostInput): Post
}
```

if you want at the same time of creating a post, to also attach it to an author then you could add the `authorId` as part of the input, here we only want to attach the Post to an existing Author:

```
input CreatePostInput {
  title: String
  authorId: ID!
  votes: Int
}
```

of course this is only the interface definition. We need to actually create the Post and link it to the Author inside the resolver.

The mutation query will look like:

```
mutation createPost {
  createPost(input: {
    title: "Title"
    votes: 345
    authorId: "authorId1" 
  }) {
    id
    title
    votes
    author {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!